# Can these three update statements be combined?

Tags: sql

I would like to be able to combine these three update statements, so I don't have to run them individually.  I would typically enter multiple "products" and multiple "baskets".

The idea is to be able to update two fields based on "fieldB" being < '5' or "fieldB" between '5' and '10' or "fieldB" > '10' without running three separate queries.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

```
UPDATE table
set fieldA = round(8.7 * fieldA,0),
    fieldB = round(8.7 * fieldB,0)                                                                               
where product in ('APPLE','BANANA')
and basket IN ('BROWN BASKET','RED BASKET','YELLOW BASKET','BLUE BASKET')
and fieldB < '5';

UPDATE table
set fieldA = round(4.3 * fieldA,0),
    fieldB = round(4.3 * fieldB,0)                                                                               
where product in ('APPLE','BANANA')
and basket IN ('BROWN BASKET','RED BASKET','YELLOW BASKET','BLUE BASKET')
and fieldB between '5' and '10';

UPDATE table
set fieldA = round(2.5 * fieldA,0),
    fieldB = round(2.5 * fieldB,0)                                                                               
where product in ('APPLE','BANANA')
and basket IN ('BROWN BASKET','RED BASKET','YELLOW BASKET','BLUE BASKET')
and fieldB > '10';
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I would suggest using a CASE statement, but how to do that would depend on what you're using - Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, ...

Comment: Which database and version are you using?  mySQL, SQL Server, Postgress, etc.  Each one supports different levels of ANSI SQL and may have different vendor specific syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statements, syntax may depend on RDBMS:

```
UPDATE table
SET fieldA = CASE WHEN fieldB < '5' THEN round(8.7 * fieldA,0)
                  WHEN fieldB BETWEEN '5' AND '10' THEN round(4.3 * fieldA,0)
                  WHEN fieldB > '10' THEN round(2.5 * fieldA,0)
             END
    ,fieldB = CASE WHEN fieldB < '5' THEN round(8.7 * fieldB,0) 
                  WHEN fieldB BETWEEN '5' AND '10' THEN round(4.3 * fieldB,0) 
                  WHEN fieldB > '10' THEN round(2.5 * fieldB,0)  
             END                                                                            
where product in ('APPLE','BANANA')
and basket IN ('BROWN BASKET','RED BASKET','YELLOW BASKET','BLUE BASKET')
```

Comment: Thank you for such quick responses.  This update statement worked.

Comment: If it worked, you should select it as the answer so others know in the future.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't even realize there was a check box to select the answer as correct.  This is only my second question I've asked.  Can't believe how fast people answer and are able to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the intention that you want is this:

```
UPDATE table
    set fieldA = round((case when fieldB < '5' then 8.7 * fieldA
                             when fieldB between '5' and '10' then 4.3 * FieldA
                             when fieldB > '10' then 2.5 * fieldA
                        end), 0),
        fieldB = round((case when fieldB < '5' then 8.7 * fieldB
                             when fieldB between '5' and '10' then 4.3 * FieldB
                             when fieldB > '10' then 2.5 * fieldB
                        end), 0)                                                                               
    where product in ('APPLE', 'BANANA') and
          basket IN ('BROWN BASKET', 'RED BASKET', 'YELLOW BASKET', 'BLUE BASKET');
```

However, this is *not* exactly what your original updates do.  The problem is that you are resetting the value for `fieldB` in each update.  So, if `FieldB` is 1 initially, it will then get set to `8.7 * FieldB` = `8.7`.  This will then be caught by the second update and so on.

If that cascading is the intention, then the arithmetic would be slightly different.  However, the idea behind the conditional updates would be the same.

Comment: Thank you for such quick responses. The first update statement worked.  I would not want the cascading.